# como puedo lograr actualizar los datos de mi bd con un UPDATE

Tags: php, sql

estoy teniendo un problema, intento hacer el update a mi bd pero aunque haga click y me aparezca sin errores sigue mostrando los mismos datos que tenia anteriormente. mi llave primaria es cedula y los otros campos son nombre, apellido, direccion, telefono. la tabla se llama administracion. como logro que el update cumpla la funcion y termine actualizando todos los datos que le ingreso en los campos de los formulario??.

cualquier consejo que me hagan aparte de la pregunta sera bienvenido.
espero me puedan ayudar amigos, espero sus respuestas :)

```
<?php
    
    $servidor="localhost";
        $usuario="root";
        $password="17122001";
        $db="sistema";

        $conexion= new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$db);

        if ($conexion->connect_error) {
            die("conexion fallida" . $conexion->connect_error);
        }
    $cedula=$_GET['cedula'];
    
    $sql="SELECT * FROM administracion where cedula = $cedula";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($sql);
    while($row= $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $nombre = $row['nombre'];
        $apellido =  $row['apellido'];
        $direccion = $row['direccion'];
        $telefono = $row['telefono'];
    }
    

?>

<div class="formulario-registro">
        
        <form action="administracion.php" method="POST">
            
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type='text' name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>" size="25" maxlength="20" minlength="3" required>

            <br />

            <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
            <input type='text' name="apellido" value="<?php echo $apellido ?>" size="25" maxlength="20" minlength="3" required>

            <br />

            <label for="cedula">Cedula</label>
            <input type='text' name="cedula" value="<?php echo $cedula ?>" size="25" maxlength="12" minlength="3" required>

            <br />

            <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
            <input type='text' name="direccion" value="<?php echo $direccion ?>" size="25" maxlength="35" minlength="3" >

            <br />

            <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
            <input type='text' name="telefono" value="<?php echo $telefono ?>" size="25" maxlength="12" minlength="3" >

            <br />
            <br />

            <label for="cargo">Cargo</label>
            <select name="cargo[]">
                  <option value="administracion"> Administracion </option>
                  <option value="docente"> Docente </option>
                  <option value="limpieza"> Limpieza </option>
                  <option value="vigilante"> Vigilante </option>
            </select>

            <br />

             <input class="boton-registro" type="submit" name="registrar" placeholder="Registrar" value="Registrar" required>

        </form>
        </div>
<?php
                $nombre2=$_POST["nombre"];
                $apellido2=$_POST["apellido"];
                $cedula2=$_POST["cedula"];
                $direccion2=$_POST["direccion"];
                $telefono2=$_POST["telefono"];
                $cargo2=$_POST["cargo"];

                $sql="UPDATE administracion SET cedula='$cedula2', nombre='$nombre2', apellido='$apellido2', direccion='$direccion2', telefono='$telefono2', cargo='$cargo2' WHERE cedula='$cedula'";

                if($conexion->query($sql) === true){
                }
                else{
                    die("ERROR: " . $conexion->error);
                }
                $conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: Si la columna `cedula` es numérica tienes que poner el valor sin comillas simples, tanto en la parte del `SET` como en el `WHERE`, algo así: `... SET cedula=$cedula ... WHERE cedula=$cedula` eso vale también para cualquier columna numérica, para `NULL` o para booleanos. Aunque generalmente la llave primaria no se suele actualizar ni suele ser editable, porque el usuario te puede provocar un lío en la BD. Por último, considera blindar tu código contra inyección SQL aplicando consultas preparadas.

Comment: Hola, ¿solucionaste este problema?

Comment: @OscarGarcia si amigo

Answer (score 1):

Diego, pude notar una diferencia en la clausula `WHERE` del `SELECT` en comparación con la del `UPDATE` y tal vez esa sea la causa.

En el select pasas la cédula como número

```
$sql="SELECT ... WHERE cedula = $cedula";
```

Pero en el update está como string

```
$sql="UPDATE ... WHERE cedula = '$cedula'";
```

Adicionalmente te comento que me causa preocupación la forma como estás construyendo las instrucciones SQL. Considera parametrizarlas porque como están, dejan todas las puertas abiertas a lo que se conoce como inyección sql. [Esta referencia](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/lecciones/php-db-inyeccion-sql.html) te puede dar más información al respecto.

**Actualización**

El otro error que me notificaste en los comentarios, es porque en el `UPDATE`, también estás tratando la cédula como un string y evidentemente es un número.

```
//   Asegurate que no esté entre comillas  |
//                                         V
$sql="UPDATE administracion SET cedula = $cedula2, ...
```

En general, cuando construyes instrucciones SQL los campos que son numéricos no van entre comillas `' '`

Comment: Hola Pablo. Te agradezco la referencia. Es muy didáctica.

Comment: ahora me da este error: ERROR: Incorrect integer value: '' for column `sistema`.`administracion`.`cedula` at row 1

Comment: @DiegoGoncalves, acabo de editar la respuesta con la explicación al segundo error

Comment: aun no funciona

Comment: Pero sigue siendo el mismo error u otro? Para poder hacer una mejor revisión será necesario que publiques la definición de la tabla donde intentas hacer el `UPDATE` y el contenido de la variable `$sql` después que concatenas todos los datos